# JavaScript Promises causing error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscription' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, promise, stripe-payments

I am using a [JS script](https://github.com/ilyanaDev/DevBetterWeb/blob/stripeSignupFlow/src/DevBetterWeb.Web/wwwroot/js/stripecheckout.js) to implement the [Stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/api) payment provider on a website. The code mainly comes from [this tutorial](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/fixed-price) from Stripe. The full code can be found [here](https://github.com/ilyanaDev/DevBetterWeb/tree/stripeSignupFlow).

Part of the script involves promises, which I am very unfamiliar with. Essentially, I need to go through a number of `.then` blocks to handle a customer's checkout and subscribe them to the service. When I run the code, I get the following error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscription' of undefined`

Below is the function causing the error, with the problematic `.then` block noted:

```
var createSubscription = async function ({ customerIdInput, paymentMethodIdInput, priceIdInput }) {

    var handlePaymentThatRequiresCustomerAction = function ({
        subscription,
        invoice,
        priceId,
        paymentMethodId,
    }) {
        {
            if (subscription && subscription.status === 'active') {
                // Subscription is active, no customer actions required.
                return { subscription, priceId, paymentMethodId };
            }

            // If it's a first payment attempt, the payment intent is on the subscription latest invoice.
            // If it's a retry, the payment intent will be on the invoice itself.
            let paymentIntent = invoice ? invoice.payment_intent : subscription.latest_invoice.payment_intent;

            if (
                paymentIntent.status === 'requires_action'
            ) {
                return stripe
                    .confirmCardPayment(paymentIntent.client_secret, {
                        payment_method: paymentMethodId,
                    })
                    .then((result) => {
                        if (result.error) {
                            // Start code flow to handle updating the payment details.
                            // Display error message in your UI.
                            // The card was declined (i.e. insufficient funds, card has expired, etc).
                            throw result;
                        } else {
                            if (result.paymentIntent.status === 'succeeded') {
                                // Show a success message to your customer.
                                return {
                                    priceId: priceId,
                                    subscription: subscription,
                                    invoice: invoice,
                                    paymentMethodId: paymentMethodId,
                                };
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        displayError(error);
                    });
            } else {
                // No customer action needed.
                return { subscription, priceId, paymentMethodId };
            }
        }    };

    var handleRequiresPaymentMethod = function () {

    };

    var onSubscriptionComplete = function (result) {
        if (result.subscription.status === 'active') {
            orderComplete();
        }

    };

    var subscriptionParams = {
        "paymentMethodId": `${paymentMethodIdInput}`,
        "customerId": `${customerIdInput}`,
        "priceId": `${priceIdInput}`
    };

    await fetch('/create-subscription', {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(subscriptionParams),
    })
        .then((response) => {
            return response.json()
        })

        // If the card is declined, display an error to the user.
        .then((result) => {
            if (result.error) {
                showError(result);
                // The card had an error when trying to attach it to a customer.
                throw result;
            }
            var output = Promise.resolve(result);
            return output;
        })
        // Normalize the result to contain the object returned by Stripe.
        // Add the additional details we need.

        .then((output) => {
            return new Promise(function (resolve) {
                resolve({
                    paymentMethodId: paymentMethodIdInput,
                        priceId: priceIdInput,
                            subscription: output,
                        });
                });

        })

        // Some payment methods require a customer to be on session
        // to complete the payment process. Check the status of the
        // payment intent to handle these actions.

//THIS IS THE THEN BLOCK CAUSING THE ERROR
        .then((value) => {
            handlePaymentThatRequiresCustomerAction({
                subscription: value.subscription,
                invoice: value.subscription.latest_invoice,
                priceId: value.priceId,
                paymentMethodId: value.paymentMethodId,
            });
        })

        // If attaching this card to a Customer object succeeds,
        // but attempts to charge the customer fail, you
        // get a requires_payment_method error.
        .then(() => handleRequiresPaymentMethod())

        // No more actions required. Provision your service for the user.
        .then(() => {
            onSubscriptionComplete();
        })

        .catch((error) => {
            // An error has happened. Display the failure to the user here.
            // We utilize the HTML element we created.
            showError(error);
        });
}
```

I'm 90% certain that the `.then` block preceding the error (below) is not fully executing before the problematic block tries to reference `value.subscription`, and that that is causing the error. However, I'm not sure how to fix that. I've tried using a [Jasmine test](https://github.com/ilyanaDev/JasmineTests/blob/main/lib/async_javascript/test2.js) to isolate the problem, but I've been unsuccessful in that avenue.

```
        .then((output) => {
            return new Promise(function (resolve) {
                resolve({
                    paymentMethodId: paymentMethodIdInput,
                        priceId: priceIdInput,
                            subscription: output,
                        });
                });

        })
//THIS IS THE THEN BLOCK CAUSING THE ERROR
        .then((value) => {
            handlePaymentThatRequiresCustomerAction({
                subscription: value.subscription,
                invoice: value.subscription.latest_invoice,
                priceId: value.priceId,
                paymentMethodId: value.paymentMethodId,
            });
        })
```

What can I do to ensure that everything executes in the proper order and avoid this error? Thanks for your help.

**UPDATE:** as Zac stated in the comments, the issue was the `OnSubscriptionComplete()` function, which I neglected to pass a value to.

Comment: Are you sure that the error is caused by this part? I think it may be thrown here `if (result.subscription.status === 'active')`, because you are not sending anything to the function `onSubscriptionComplete`, could you double-check and confirm?

Comment: you're absolutely right. Thank you so much!

Comment: Also you don’t need to return a new promise from a then